# Visual Studio 2022 can't find header on cmake: C1083 and E1682

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2022

I have a cmake project where I have a folder called App that has an executable and a folder called Engine that is a dll. On the same directory there is a folder called Third-part that has my libraries. In it I'm using ImGUI which is a header only library. I've added imgui to Engine like this:

Engine/CMakeLists.txt:

```
# IMGUI Configuration
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Third-party/ImGUI/includes//Backends/)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Third-party/ImGUI/includes/Base/)

set(IMGUI_BUILD
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Third-party/ImGUI/libs/Base/imgui.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Third-party/ImGUI/libs/Base/imgui_widgets.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Third-party/ImGUI/libs/Base/imgui_tables.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Third-party/ImGUI/libs/Base/imgui_draw.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Third-party/ImGUI/libs/Base/imgui_demo.cpp

    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Third-party/ImGUI/libs/Backends/imgui_impl_glfw.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Third-party/ImGUI/libs/Backends/imgui_impl_opengl3.cpp
)
...

add_library (Engine SHARED ${IMGUI_BUILD} ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

And inside Engine I use it like this:

```
#include "imgui.h"
#include "imgui_internal.h"
#include "imgui_impl_glfw.h"
#include "imgui_impl_opengl3.h"
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

I made sure the paths are correct but I'm still getting these errors:

```
Error (inactive)    E1696   cannot open source file "imgui.h"   App.exe (App\App.exe)
...
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'imgui.h': No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong? These are just basic includes. I use the same command for my normal header files and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the reason was that I've included everything in Engine.hpp which is exposed to the App exe. And since App does not include imgui it crashed. I've put all the headers to Engine.cpp and everything works now